# What is the crash causing fault?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

Is the problem an out of bounds exception for i exceeds the array limit?

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int*  myarray = 0;
    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)` - this should probably be `for (i = 1; i < len; i++)` - because arrays are zero based you want to stop 1 before the length.

Comment: I know, my assignment is to take this piece of code and find out which line is causing the crash. I know about the out of bounds exception that will occur but I don't know which line in particular is causing the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you provided.

The first issue is that you haven't actually allocated any memory for `myarray`. You just created a pointer, which currently points to `NULL`.

Create a static array

```
int myarray[10];
```

Or dynamically

```
int *myarray = new int[10];
```

The second issue is you'll most likely access outside the bounds of `array` in the for loop. Because arrays indices are zero based, you'll what to check `i < len`, rather than `i <= len`.

Comment: That would be true if he started his loop at 0, but it starts at 1.

Comment: It doesn't matter where he starts, `i` will end up equal to `10`, which is outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I need to find out what line the fault will occur at? Would that be 4 or 11?

Comment: The fault will occur on line 4 because you're assigning to the `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int*  myarray = 0;
    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```

You never declare the size of your array in main. You need to either allocating the size either statically or dynamically. You currently have an int pointer that's pointed at nothing. And then passing that pointer in and trying to access it using:

```
array[i] = i;
```

***This is the working code***

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) {

    array = new int[len];

    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int*  myarray = 0;
    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```